# What happens to internal stock when a company goes public?

Tags: stocks, ipo

If you hold stock in a company that is not publicly traded, what will happen to that stock if the company becomes publicly traded?

Answer (score 1):

You'd likely be subject to a [lock-up period](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answer/12/ipo-lockup-period.asp) before you could sell the shares along with possibly having other rules about how you could sell your shares as you'd likely be seen as an insider that may have information that gives you an unfair advantage for selling the stock possibly. Depending on how far in advance you hold the shares, you may or may not have adjustments in the valuation and number of shares as some companies may do a split or reverse split when preparing for an IPO. A company I worked for in the late 1990s had an IPO and my stock options had a revised strike price because of a reverse stock split that was done prior to the IPO.